# Dragging a sprite with cocos2d produces a lag

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have the following piece of code to drag a sprite around the screen using cocos2D:

```
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
    oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
    oldTouchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:oldTouchLocation];

    CGPoint translation = ccpSub(touchLocation, oldTouchLocation);
    CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd([mySprite position], translation);
    [mySprite setPosition:newPos];
}
```

The sprite is shown on the screen and I can drag it around the screen with my finger, but the sprite is slower than my finger lagging behind about a quarter of an inch.

What can I do to avoid this lag?

Thanks,

GA

Comment: Did you try it on a device or the simulator ?

Comment: Both. And I also tried it in the device disconnected from xcode. The issue is always there.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? i'm experiencing the same. writing an OpenGL game that tracks the finger but there's a noticeable lag. am tempted to use finger velocity to predict where it will be to compensate lag... but its seems like an ugly hack that could work against me...

Comment: I didn't really solve the problem, because I found out that somehow the lagging makes a sense on my game. In my case the finger is moving magnets through the screen, so I added some tricks to make the finger itself a magnet that attracts others. In this case the lagging is even necessary. When I was trying to solve it, I tried to increase the force applied to the mouse joint and that reduced the lagging a bit, but I couldn't remove it completely.